# Inserting a node before a specific node in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have implemented a method to insert a new node before a specific node.

```
#ifndef FORWARD_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST_H
#define FORWARD_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace forward_singly_linked_list {
    typedef struct Node {
        std::string data;
        struct Node *nextPointer;
    } Node;

    typedef Node *NodeP;

    class LinkedList {
    private:
        int elementsCount;
        Node *head;

    public:
        LinkedList() {
            head = NULL;
            elementsCount = 0;
        }

        int get_length() const
        {
            return elementsCount;
        }

        // ... ... ...

        void add_before(std::string value, std::string before)
        {
            // empty an area in the memory, and
            // save the address of the empty area in 'newNode'
            Node *newNode = new Node();
            // assign 'value' to the 'data' section of the
            // area pointed by 'newNode'
            newNode->data = value;

            Node * copyOfHead = head;

            if (copyOfHead == nullptr)
            {
                // the list is empty.
                // there is no possibility to find 'before'.
                // so, return.
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                bool found = false;
                Node * previousNode = nullptr;
                while (copyOfHead != nullptr)
                {
                    if (copyOfHead->data == before)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousNode = copyOfHead;
                        copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextPointer;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (previousNode != nullptr)
                {
                    newNode->nextPointer = previousNode->nextPointer;
                    previousNode->nextPointer = newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    newNode->nextPointer = head;
                    head = newNode;
                }
            }

            elementsCount++;
        }
        

        // ... ... ...

        void print() {
            Node *copyOfHead = head;
            while (copyOfHead != NULL) {
                std::cout << copyOfHead->data;
                copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextPointer;
            }
            std::cout<<"\n\n";
        }
    public:
        static int Test() {
            forward_singly_linked_list::LinkedList list;

            list.print();
//            list.add_at_tail("A");
//            list.add_at_tail("B");
//            list.add_at_tail("C");
            list.print();

            list.add_at("-XXX-", 1);
            list.print();

            return 0;
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Personally, I don't like it because it uses an extra pointer `previousNode`. I have a feeling that it could be improved.

How can I improve the implementation?

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: *Personally, I don't like it. I have a feeling that it could be improved.* -- Why do you think it needs to be improved?  Even [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) doesn't have ready-made functions to insert an item before another, since that's the nature of singly-linked lists.  You basically have to write some sort of loop-and-check code for a singly-linked-list to insert an item before another.

Comment: If you wanted to remove `previousNode` you'd probably have to switch the while loop to check the _next_ node's data. That would require adding in extra checks to see if the head matches the search string. I don't know if that would be much cleaner.

Comment: Why not use a variant linked list: intrusive double list, then remove the front element can be done in constant time, it's much faster than your implementation. Single linked lists have many limitations can their usage is not too wide.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is about link the previous node to input/target node, then link the target/input node to current node.
Here is my code using simple loop index(i) instead of using extra pointer

```
void Sll::add_at_index( int ind , int value ){

 Node *target = new Node( value ) ;

 if( ind == 1){

      target->next = head ;
      head = target ;

 }else if( ind == length){

      tail->next = target ;
      tail = target ;
      tail->next = nullptr ;

 }else{

      Node *curr =head ;
      for( int i = 1 ; i < length ; i++ ){

           if( i+1 == ind){

                Node *Mynext = curr->next ;
                curr->next = target ;
                target->next = Mynext ;
                break ;
           }
           curr = curr->next ;

      }
 }
 length++ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Become a two-star programmer:

```
void add_before(std::string value, std::string_view before) {
    auto p = &head;
    while (*p && (*p)->data != before)
        p = &(*p)->nextPointer;
    if (!*p)
        return;
    *p = new Node {
        .data = std::move(value),
        .nextPointer = *p,
    };
    ++elementsCount;
}
```